# Perl created files with future timestamps on FreeBSD 9.3

Tags: perl, file-io, freebsd

I just encountered some strange behavior with Perl 5.16.3 on FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p3.  We've got a cron job which runs every five minutes and generates some text status files.  I just happened to list the contents of the output directory and saw that the timestamps for some of the files *were in the future!*  The files are created like this:

```
if (open(OUT, "> $status_file_path")) {
    print OUT "$status_info\n";
    close OUT;
}
```

Now, the file handle OUT is used in several places, however it is opened and closed within the same block as shown above.  And like I said, out of ten files, only a few had future dates when displayed using *ls*.

For example, files with the current date had timestamps like *04/02/2015 20:29:46*, files with *future* timestamps were out in November, e.g. *11/10/2015 09:38:41*.

What might be going on here?

**EDIT**

I've got two tests running:

1) a perl script running a loop of 1000 iterations, sleeping a random time up to 10 seconds between iterations, using the open/print/close logic to create an output file and abort the script if the file's modification time is in the future.

2) a cron entry to touch a test file every minute, e.g. *touch /home/test/test_file_date_with_cron.txt*

**TEST RESULTS**

Neither of the tests generated output files with a timestamp in the future.

This is scary.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the filesystem info, the files are written in the /usr directory.

```
# df -h
Filesystem           Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/gpt/gprootfs      2G    133M    1.7G     7%    /
devfs                1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/gpt/gpusrfs     431G    3.8G    392G     1%    /usr
procfs               4.0k    4.0k      0B   100%    /proc
```

**EDIT 3**

Running the script outside of cron for several hundred iterations didn't duplicate the problem.  HOWEVER, I just found some other files, which are created by a CGI script which have the future dates:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 test  test   5783 Nov 10  2015 Config.xml_20150210_104151
-rw-r--r--  1 test  test  34548 Nov 10  2015 Config2.xml_20150210_104151
-rw-r--r--  1 test  test   6105 Nov 10  2015 Config.xml_20151109_232210
-rw-r--r--  1 test  test  34554 Nov 10  2015 Config2.xml_20151109_232210
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  test   2075 Nov  9  2015 Config.xml_20151109_231055
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  test   1232 Nov  9  2015 Config2.xml_20151109_231055
```

These are archive files, which get moved and renamed with the file's mtime timestamp. Note that BOTH *ls* and Perl's *stat()* function report the future date -- stat() is used to generate the file's timestamp portion of the name.

Looking at the first entry, ls reports "Nov 10  2015", whereas when the CGI script processed it, Perl's stat() reported "20150210_104151", i.e. "Feb 02 2015" which is most likely correct.

Further down, we see ls showing "Nov 10  2015" and stat() reported "20151109_232210", i.e. "Nov 09 2015".

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior using only the code you've posted here?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I wrote a test script to write files in a loop, waiting a few seconds in between each write, and of course it didn't duplicate the problem.

Comment: @toolic I edited my post to show the future dates, which were months in the future, so it doesn't seem like a clock drift issue.

Comment: Try a crontab that just uses [touch](http://man.cx/touch) to create or touch the modification date. See whether the problem is with running Perl or the way cron runs.

Comment: Perhaps there's another process changing the modified date that you're not aware of. Setting the modified date of a file to the future is trivial: `touch -d tomorrow foo && ls -l foo`

Comment: @DavidW.  Trying a cron entry which runs every minute and does "touch test_file.txt" now.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Fortunately, I do know that these particular files are created and modified by only one cron job.  They are read elsewhere, however only written in one place.

Comment: Are these files being created on a shared filesystem, like NFS for example? Check the clock on the file server.

Comment: @Kenster Nope, it's a standalone BSD box.

Comment: What are the exact `ls` options you use to determine the file date and time?

Comment: @Jens "ll" which is an alias for "ls -lt" showed me the initial problem.  The detailed timestamps which I mentioned in the post were from an administrative GUI which is perl based and uses (stat())[9] to get the files mtime and passes that to localtime() to construct the display datetime.

Comment: What is the server time zone?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you run the script outside of cron? If so, you can try running with the [debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html). Set a watchpoint (`w -M 'foo' < 0`, where `foo` is the filename) and continue (`c`) until the value changes.

Comment: @SinanÜnür /etc/rc.conf has timezone="America/New_York".

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That's essentially what I did with the 1000-write test, the script was run from the command line outside of cron.  In 1000 iterations, the file's modification timestamp was fine.

Comment: You said "*a* perl script running a loop of 1000 iterations." I'm asking if you ran *the* script that is exhibiting this behavior in cron. If not, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ah, no I haven't done that yet.  Will try that now.

Comment: OK. I wanted to see if the bit patterns for the good and bad times had any relationship.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yeah, I saw this last Thursday right before everyone was leaving the office for the long weekend, and I didn't capture the "ls" details for the files.  d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

Finding those additional archived config files helped me track down the cause, which was as others have suggested, that the system date and timezone changed.

```
From:  1447147328 and America/Adak
To:    1426637771 and America/New_York
```

What was throwing me off, was that I thought the cron script wrote ALL of the output files each time it executes, but that's not the case.  The files have different "refresh intervals".